# instantiate objects using for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to take 4/8/12/etc. args and apply args 0-3 to ball[0], args 4-7 to ball[1], etc. Currently it sets the last set of args to every ball, so both balls have args 4-7 for its four values.

```
int m = 0;
for(int p = 0; p<ss.balln; p++) {
  try {
    System.out.println(p);
     ball[p].posx = Double.parseDouble(args[m]);
    System.out.println(m);
     m++;
     ball[p].posy = Double.parseDouble(args[m]);
    System.out.println(m);

     m++;
     ball[p].velx = Double.parseDouble(args[m]);
    System.out.println(m);
     m++;
     ball[p].vely = Double.parseDouble(args[m]);
    System.out.println(m);
     m++;

  }
  catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      System.out.println("Try using numbers.");
      System.exit( 0 );
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: how are you instantiating the `ball` array?

Comment: I don't see any objects being instantiated here... except maybe `Double`s or a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score -1):

Presumably every element of the `ball` array is pointing to the same object. You need to create a new instance for each offset.

```
Ball[] balls = new Ball[ss.balln];
for (int i=0; i<balls.length; ++i) {
    balls[i] = new Ball();
]
```

So the error is in the code above that which you have shown.

Even better, use a `List` and create a `Ball` when needed.

```
List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();
...
   Ball ball = new Ball();
   ...
   balls.add(ball);
```

Comment: Why the down votes, people? This is a very good answer, especially that OP didn't even provide relevant code.